# geometric intuition behind rationalizing denominator in order to find limits

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

Given a question such as: compute the limit

$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sqrt{t^2+9}-3}{t^2}$

the answer becomes apparent only once we rationalize the denominator. 
My question is: why? (i.e. how does this work)? what are we really doing here, and what is the geometric/algebraic significance of this. To clarify, I obviously see its usefulness, i just have no intuition as to how it works.

Comment: Rationalizing the rational function is merely a technique that works well in these scenarios.  It is merely an algebraic manipulation that clears up the mess.

Comment: I don't see what is to be rationalized in the denominator of your own example. Maybe you meant to ask about $\lim \limits _{t \to 0} \dfrac {t^2} {\sqrt {t^2 + 9} - 3}$?

Comment: the limit only becomes apparent after multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{t^2+9}+3}{\sqrt{t^2+9}+3}$

Comment: @JoeGaige: In that case, what you rationalize in your example is the *numerator*.

Answer (score 1):

When an expression goes to $0/0$ in a limit, it's because there's some factor in the top and bottom going to zero.  Fun limit problems hide that factor.  In your example the factor is $t^2$.  To hide it, write $t^2 +9 -9$ and factor by
difference of squares: $(\sqrt{t^2+9}-3)(\sqrt{t^2+9}+3)$ and discard the bit which doesn't go to zero.